# Draw R-tree from picture

Tags: database, data-structures, r-tree

I am having some difficulty understanding how to draw an R-tree of 2D rectangles from a picture of its structure. I have quickly drawn a sketch of some rectangles, just as an example to help me understand.

My questions are:

- What does the R-Tree (the logical structure) look like?
- Are any of the below options correct?

```
         R11                (root node with one MBR, this seems wrong!)
    |     |          |
    R8    R9        R10     (internal nodes)
    |     |          |
  R1 R2  R3 R4 R5  R6 R7    (leaves)
```

or

```
    R8 R9 R10               (root node with multiple MBRs)
    |     |          |
  R1 R2  R3 R4 R5  R6 R7    (leaves)
```

[image]

**Reference:** The original paper by Guttman: [here](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/SI-LS/papers/Gut84.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at the picture in my paper, which you referenced.  It was meant to clarify the structure and answer questions like yours.  It is on page 49.

Comment: In case this is not a prank, I feel incredibly humbled to get a response from Guttman himself. I apologize for my ignorance, sir!

Comment: Not a prank.  I hope your r-tree is useful to you, or at least interesting!

Comment: This is purely an exercise to understand R-trees better. Thank you!

Comment: After re-reading page 49, I see that the answer is likely the second option in my question. Then do I simply "discard" or not use R11 here?